# Query that fetch messages for a specific user

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, fetch

I have a messages table like the following, how to fetch messages for a specific user, that is, fetch one most recent message with one user.For example, *user1* has messages with *user2* and *user3*,how to fetch one most recent message between *user1* and *user2*, one most recent message between *user1* and *user3*?

```
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    sender_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'))
    body = Column(Text())
    recipient_id = Column(Integer())
    created_at = Column(DateTime())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime())
```

The SQL I could figure out is following, but it is not enough.Could you help me? Thanks a lot,:).

```
session.query(Message).\
filter(or_(Message.user_id==user.id, Message.recipient_id==user.id))
```

Comment: This question is very difficult to read or understand. Essentially you want the max(id) grouped by sender_id or recipient_id. Ir, if you can't trust the id's to be strictly increasing with "created at" then you could do a join involving select max(id), grouped by recipient and sent-by from your data table and joined with max(created_at) grouped again by sender_id and recipient_id from your data table (obviously join on the recipient and senders ids, as well as the date). But based on what you have here, it's hard to provide actual code. The question is not clear. To start, that's not SQL....

Comment: @evanv, thanks, i think using sql group is correct, but i can not figure it out, i have updated my question.

Comment: @evanv, sorry, stackoverflow stop me editing question today

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

session.query(Message).\
filter(or_(Message.user_id==user.id, Message.recipient_id==user.id)).\
order_by(desc(Message.created_at)).\
first()
```

Comment: @dmvianna, sorry, maybe my question is not clear, your help is not correct, :)

Answer (score 0):

Code below should give you an example using `created_at` as the decision column for the *latest*. You can easily change it to be `updated_at`.
Note that for two users (`A and B`) it will return both *latest* messages: latest from `A->B` and latest `B->A`.

```
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Text, Integer, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import func, and_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text())

class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    sender_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'))
    body = Column(Text())
    recipient_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('users.id'))
    created_at = Column(DateTime())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime())

    sender = relationship(User, backref="messages_sent", foreign_keys=sender_id)
    recipient = relationship(User, backref="messages_recv", foreign_keys=recipient_id)


Base.metadata.create_all()
users = u1, u2, u3 = [
        User(name='user1'),
        User(name='user2'),
        User(name='user3'),
        ]
session.add_all(users)

session.add_all([
    Message(sender=u1, recipient=u2, body="bod12-a", created_at = date(2014, 1, 13)),
    Message(sender=u1, recipient=u2, body="bod12-X", created_at = date(2014, 1, 3)),

    Message(sender=u2, recipient=u3, body="bod23-X", created_at = date(2014, 1, 13)),
    Message(sender=u2, recipient=u3, body="bod23-a", created_at = date(2013, 1, 13)),
    ])
session.flush()

subq = (session
        .query(Message.sender_id, Message.recipient_id,
            func.max(Message.created_at).label("max_created_at"))
        .group_by(Message.sender_id, Message.recipient_id)
        ).subquery("subq")

q = (session
        .query(Message)
        .join(subq, and_(
            Message.sender_id == subq.c.sender_id,
            Message.recipient_id == subq.c.recipient_id,
            Message.created_at == subq.c.max_created_at)
            )
        ).all()
for x in q:
    print(x.sender_id, x.recipient_id, x.body)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your relationship is a little different from mine.